# Spring Security : Encrypt password

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring 3.2.5. Righ now i am hashing password using

```
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        messageDigest.update(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] digestBytes = messageDigest.digest();
```

I want to secure password using methods provided by spring. I searched internet and most of the post are very old. So any example will be fine.

Comment: This isn't encryption. This is hashing. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: i want to hash password using spring security methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder` class. It is a lot less hassle, you don't have to worry about salt and iterations - the details are completely encapsulated within the encoder.

```
<!-- password encoder -->
<beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder" />


<!-- This is the authentication manager -->
<authentication-manager>
   <authentication-provider user-service-ref="authService">
    <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
   </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Visit [this](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/StandardPasswordEncoder.html) site to know more.

Answer (score 4):

Using a password encoder with the `<password-encoder>` property as the other answers suggest is correct. I would also like to add that recommended encoder to use is  BCryptPasswordEncoder as Spring doc [recommends](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/StandardPasswordEncoder.html) when trying to use the old Standard encoder:

```
 If you are developing a new system, BCryptPasswordEncoder is a better choice both in terms of security and interoperability with other languages.
```

You can also read more background details on  on  hashing [here,](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) where BCrypt algorithm is also one of the suggested algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do it using spring security,
Add below lines in spring-security.xml beans:

**Using SHA-512**,

```
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <password-encoder hash="sha-512" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

**or Using md5**:

```
        <authentication-manager>
            <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
                <password-encoder hash="md5" />
            </authentication-provider>
        </authentication-manager>
```

About **UserDetailsService**:
UserDetailsService provide method to load user by username.
[More about UserDetailsService](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html)

If you want to load user by any other attribute like email or mobile number then u need to write custom class which implements `UserDetailsService` and write your implemetation in that class.

[Refer this link for custom userDetailsService implementation](http://javapointers.com/tutorial/spring-custom-userdetailsservice-example/)

Answer (score 2):

I find that this is the simplest way, thus this is the one I use:

```
<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <sec:password-encoder hash="sha-256">
            <sec:salt-source user-property="username" />
        </sec:password-encoder>
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

the main point here is that the `password-encoder` is defined in the XML itself (and even the salt, if needed), so no extra code is needed. This is "Spring's way"...